# Please recommend a good approach to learning HTML5 with SASS to start a new project

Tags: html, sass

I hope this question isn't too vague.   I'm a backend developer, and haven't kept up with the front end tech.   I would like to build a simple page with HTML5 and SASS to up-skill.   Do you recommend a boilerplate solution that would be good start?  By that, I mean, I ideally, I'd like to start with a quality html5 base file and go from there.  It's hard to say exactly what I'm looking for.  If I could I wouldn't need it.

Comment: Why do you think you want to use SASS? It is approaching the end of its life cycle.

Comment: SASS has been in the back of my head for awhile.  Only now just focusing on it.   End of life cycle?  Really.

Comment: To answer your question, well, on one medium sized project, we have nearly 1000 lines of css.   I see SASS as a way to DRY out and simplify the styles.

Comment: You can dry out your CSS just fine with appropriate refactoring and lightweight, modern CSS pre- and post-processors. SASS will merely complicate your stack and your chain.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite HTML5 boilerplate to start with is this one (it doesn't directly incorporate SASS though):

https://html5boilerplate.com/

This describes how to set up a nice clean SASS file structure:

http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project

And after that the SASS website itself has great documentation to get started:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html